# Searching multidimensional JSON array for value using generic keys - php

Tags: php, arrays, json, key, key-value

I'm trying to search a complex JSON array which is converted from a SOAP XML response for a specific value. The keys are really generic.

```
 ["configurableFields"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["configurableField"]=>
    array(6) {
      [0]=>
      array(3) {
        ["label"]=>
        string(15) "Job Information"
        ["value"]=>
        string(15) "Job Information"
        ["criteria"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["criterion"]=>
          array(3) {
            [0]=>
            array(2) {
              ["label"]=>
              string(19) "SAP Position Number"
              ["value"]=>
              string(3) "TBC"
            }
            [1]=>
            array(2) {
              ["label"]=>
              string(20) "Assignment JD Number"
              ["value"]=>
              string(6) "AG111111"
            }
            [2]=>
            array(2) {
              ["label"]=>
              string(20) "Generic JD Reference"
              ["value"]=>
              string(5) "C11111"
            }
          }
        }
      }
      [1]=>
      array(3) {
        ["label"]=>
        string(16) "Hours and salary"
        ["value"]=>
        string(5) "Hours"
        ["criteria"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["criterion"]=>
          array(3) {
            [0]=>
            array(2) {
              ["label"]=>
              string(14) "hours per week"
              ["value"]=>
              string(2) "37"
            }
            [1]=>
            array(2) {
              ["label"]=>
              string(14) "weeks per year"
              ["value"]=>
              string(2) "52"
            }
            [2]=>
            array(2) {
              ["label"]=>
              string(6) "Salary"
              ["value"]=>
              string(11) "£29,636 pa"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

How in the above example do I search the array for the label "Salary" then get the value string for "£29, 636 pa".

Sorry if i'm missing something simple. I don't have any starting code as I was just printing the value by targetting it within a foreach loop.

EDIT: Forgot to add the placement of the values in the array can change if some of the data is missing.

Comment: If you used the original XML, you could use XPath which allows you to search for content at any level.

Comment: Probably this ^^^^^^^^^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can index that array by the `label` so you can use it for other values in the next steps:

```
$array = array_column($array["configurableFields"]["configurableField"], null, "label");
```

Then you will have `Job Information` and `Hours and salary` keys.  Then you can index the `criterion` by the `label`:

```
$HoursSalary = array_column($array["Hours and salary"]["criteria"]["criterion"], null, "label");
```

And finally access the `value` of the `Salary` key:

```
echo $HoursSalary["Salary"]["value"];
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Exactly what I was after, much appreciated.